# How to decode a JSON into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, decode

I am trying to decode a JSON I get from a RESTful API into a pandas dataframe. Here is snippet of how the JSON looks like:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":26,
         "name":"A",
         "comment":"",
         "start_time_plan":null,
         "start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "start_time_delta":null,
         "start_time_score":null,
         "start_time_score_achievement":null,
         "start_time_traffic_light":null,
         "end_time_plan":null,
         "end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "end_time_delta":null,
         "end_time_score":null,
         "end_time_score_achievement":null,
         "end_time_traffic_light":null,
         "status":0,
         "measure_schedule_revision_id":63,
         "responsible_user_id":3,
         "created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:14",
         "created_user_id":3,
         "modified_time":"2016-09-21 16:33:41",
         "modified_user_id":3,
         "model":"Activity"
      },
      {
         "id":27,
         "name":"B",
         "comment":"",
         "start_time_plan":null,
         "start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "start_time_delta":null,
         "start_time_score":null,
         "start_time_score_achievement":null,
         "start_time_traffic_light":null,
         "end_time_plan":null,
         "end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "end_time_delta":null,
         "end_time_score":null,
         "end_time_score_achievement":null,
         "end_time_traffic_light":null,
         "status":0,
         "measure_schedule_revision_id":63,
         "responsible_user_id":3,
         "created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:48",
         "created_user_id":3,
         "modified_time":"2016-10-16 18:14:36",
         "modified_user_id":1,
         "model":"Activity"
      }
   ]
}
```

My goal is to get a dataframe with two columns consisting of `end_time_delta` and `start_time_delta` and to build a simple scatterplot from it.

Here is what I do:

```
u = 'https://myurl.com'

# urllib3 + poolmanager for requests
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()


# get the JSON
import json
r = http.request('GET', u)
result = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))

for item in result['data']:
    print(item['end_time_delta'])

for item in result['data']:
    print(item['start_time_delta'])

# decode JSON to pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json( result, orient='values')
```

I manage to get the JSON and forloop through it. But I can't decode it to a pandas dataframe. How does that work?

(I tried myself out with pandas read_json. But I am not sure, it is a smart idea. It is not working anyhow.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(j)['data'])
```

get the columns you want

```
df[['start_time_delta', 'end_time_delta']]
```

scatter plot with

```
df[['start_time_delta', 'end_time_delta']].plot.scatter(0, 1)
```

---

***setup***

```
import json

j = """{
   "success":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "id":26,
         "name":"A",
         "comment":"",
         "start_time_plan":null,
         "start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "start_time_delta":null,
         "start_time_score":null,
         "start_time_score_achievement":null,
         "start_time_traffic_light":null,
         "end_time_plan":null,
         "end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "end_time_delta":null,
         "end_time_score":null,
         "end_time_score_achievement":null,
         "end_time_traffic_light":null,
         "status":0,
         "measure_schedule_revision_id":63,
         "responsible_user_id":3,
         "created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:14",
         "created_user_id":3,
         "modified_time":"2016-09-21 16:33:41",
         "modified_user_id":3,
         "model":"Activity"
      },
      {
         "id":27,
         "name":"B",
         "comment":"",
         "start_time_plan":null,
         "start_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "start_time_delta":null,
         "start_time_score":null,
         "start_time_score_achievement":null,
         "start_time_traffic_light":null,
         "end_time_plan":null,
         "end_time_actual":"2016-09-13 00:00:00",
         "end_time_delta":null,
         "end_time_score":null,
         "end_time_score_achievement":null,
         "end_time_traffic_light":null,
         "status":0,
         "measure_schedule_revision_id":63,
         "responsible_user_id":3,
         "created_time":"2016-09-13 11:29:48",
         "created_user_id":3,
         "modified_time":"2016-10-16 18:14:36",
         "modified_user_id":1,
         "model":"Activity"
      }
   ]
}"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I can see how that should work. But I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'loads'`

Comment: @Rachel it seems you've masked the name `json` with a `dict`; do `del json` or `import json` and try it again.

Comment: @Rachel I've updated my post with the setup.  Hopefully that clears up any confusion.

Comment: @piRSquared @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard Thank you both! However, I am trying not to save the JSON - which in reality is quite long - or to keep it in the code. I understand `json.loads()` requires a string. But I sofar use `r = http.request('GET', falcon)` and then put the json to  dict with `j = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))` . I hence get the error `the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`. How do I solve that?

Comment: I solved the isse by firs using GET and then by dumping the JSON into a string. No it works. By I figure there has to be a smoother way - i.e. without the dump?